# MySQL/PHP - Time Passed

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

How can I calculate the amount of 5 minuet periods passed with a datetime type?

is it possible?

```
//Update AP (+1 points every 5 mins)

//          PLAN OF ACTION (for ap update)!
// 1. check how long it has been since last update 
// 2. calculate how many 5 min periods has passed 
// 3. update $ap accordinly 
if ($last_ap_update != "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){ //Make sure last_ap_update has a value


}
else{ //If the last update is NULL, It must be players first page load. So set datetime equal to NOW
    $query = "UPDATE `stats` SET `last_ap_update` = NOW() WHERE `member_id` = {$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']}"; 
    $queryresult = @mysql_query($query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract past unix timestamp from current unix timestamp then divide result by 300 (60*5).

You can convert a MySQL datetime into a unix timestamp by either:

- Using the SQL [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
  function, i.e., `SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_ap_update)`
- Pass a datetime string into
  PHP's [strtotime](http://strtotime), i.e, `strtotime('2009-10-31 12:59:59');`